# setting Settings.System.AUTO_TIME doesn't update system time

Tags: android, datetime, android-2.2-froyo

My android application sets

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 1);
```

using `permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` and `permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` in the manifest.

> It works partially--the Auto Time setting does get set correctly. 
>   However the system time is not updated.  When I select Automatic in
>   the Date & time settings app the time is automatically updated from
>   the network, but this doesn't happen when I set Automatic from my app.
>   Do I need to do something additional or need an additional permission?

Comment: Its not possible to set permission.WRITE_SETTINGS in latest version of android...Only system app can use this permission..

Answer (score 1):

Use Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on GPS/wireless networks in location settings?

Have you turned on Internet connection?

The system needs to know where you are and I am not quite sure if it needs to contact a timeserver to determine the actual date/time.